# What is the use of using star in python before code statement here

Tags: python-3.x, intersection

Running
`d = [{1,2,3,4}, {2,3,4}, {3,4,5,6,7}, {4,7,9}]`
`set.intersection(*[x for x in d])`
gives '4' but running
`set.intersection([x for x in d])` only
gives error message saying "TypeError: descriptor 'intersection' requires a 'set' object but received a 'list'". What is the use of '*' here ?

Comment: `intersection` is not a class method. It's an instance method, so it expects its first argument to be a set, whether you use `s.intersection(...)` or `set.intersection(s, ...)`. (The *other* arguments can be arbitrary iterables of hashable values.)

Answer (score 2):

It serves to unpack a collection into several isolated values.

For example, in your code, it will do the same as `set.intersection({1,2,3,4}, {2,3,4}, {3,4,5,6,7}, {4,7,9})`, with 4 arguments.

Note that it is not necessary to have a list comprehension inside, `set.intersection(*d)` is equivalent.

Resources:
[What does the star and doublestar operator mean in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-and-doublestar-operator-mean-in-a-function-call)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-unpack-using-star-expression-in-python

Comment: Which  category is this explanation is falling under as shown here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-does-the-Star-operator-mean-in-Python or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters